# How can I find last modified timestamp for a table in Hive?

Tags: hive, timestamp, last-modified

I'm trying to fetch last modified timestamp of a table in Hive.

Comment: What do you mean by *"last modified timestamp"*? Is that some metadata information i.e. when the last ALTER command was run? Or some data i.e. one of the columns containing a `Timestamp` type?

Comment: Please ensure you have a code sample and/or more elaboration on what you want to achieve. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

Please use the below command:

```
show TBLPROPERTIES table_name ('transient_lastDdlTime');
```

Comment: Does this show the 'CreateTime' or the last time the table was modified?

Comment: This shows table creation time, unfortunately.

Comment: it will change after table altered.
hive> show TBLPROPERTIES test ('transient_lastDdlTime');
 **1669968118**  
hive> alter table test add columns( name varchar(100));
hive> show TBLPROPERTIES test ('transient_lastDdlTime');
**1669968379**

Answer (score 10):

Get the transient_lastDdlTime from your Hive table.

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;
```

Then copy paste the transient_lastDdlTime in below query to get the value as timestamp.

```
SELECT CAST(from_unixtime(your_transient_lastDdlTime_value) AS timestamp);
```

Comment: This gives the creation time rather than the last modified time.

Answer (score 4):

With the help of above answers I have created a simple solution for the forthcoming developers.

```
time_column=`beeline --hivevar db=hiveDatabase --hivevar tab=hiveTable --silent=true --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 -e 'show create table ${db}.${tab}' | egrep 'transient_lastDdlTime'`
time_value=`echo $time_column | sed 's/[|,)]//g' | awk -F '=' '{print $2}' | sed "s/'//g"`
tran_date=`date -d @$time_value +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`
echo $tran_date
```

I used beeline alias. Make sure you setup alias properly and invoke the above script. If there are no alias used then use the complete beeline command(with jdbc connection) by replacing beeline above. Leave a question in the comment if any.

Answer (score 3):

Here there is already an answer for how to see last modified date for a hive table. I am just sharing how to check last modified date for a hive table partition.

1. Connect to hive cluster to run hive queries. In most of the cases, you can simply connect by running hive command : hive
2. `DESCRIBE FORMATTED <database>.<table_name> PARTITION(<partition_column>=<partition_value>);`
3. In the response you will see something like this : `transient_lastDdlTime   1631640957`
4. `SELECT CAST(from_unixtime(1631640957) AS timestamp);`

Answer (score 1):

You may get the timestamp by executing

```
describe formatted table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

you can execute the below command and convert the output of `transient_lastDdlTime` from timestamp to date.
It will give the last modified timestamp for the table.

```
show create table TABLE_NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

This `transient_lastDdlTime` gives when the last select was run, not necessary modified

Answer (score -3):

if you are using mysql as metadata use following...

```
select TABLE_NAME, UPDATE_TIME, TABLE_SCHEMA from TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'employees';
```