# How to find last_updated time of a hive table using presto query?

Tags: sql, hive, presto, last-modified, trino

I am using **trino-python-client** to query the **hive** database https://github.com/trinodb/trino-python-client:

```
from trino.dbapi import connect

conn = connect(
    host="<host>",
    port=<port>,
    user="<username>",
    catalog="hive",
    schema="default",
)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM <schema_name>.<table_name>")
rows = cur.fetchall()
```

Now I want to fetch the **last_updated** time of a hive table using trino connection. So I tried running the following queries, but none of them worked.

1. `describe formatted <table_name>` Source: [How can I find last modified timestamp for a table in Hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41468759/how-can-i-find-last-modified-timestamp-for-a-table-in-hive)

> Query failed: mismatched input '<table_name>'. Expecting: '.', <EOF>

2. `SELECT transient_lastddltime FROM "<table_name>$properties"`
   Source: [How to find when record was last updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56546105/how-to-find-when-record-was-last-updated)

> Query failed: Table '<table_name>$properties' does not exist

3. `show TBLPROPERTIES <table_name> ('transient_lastDdlTime');`
   Source: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/sql-ref-syntax-aux-show-tblproperties.html

> Query failed: mismatched input 'TBLPROPERTIES'. Expecting: 'CATALOGS', 'COLUMNS', 'CREATE', 'CURRENT', 'FUNCTIONS', 'GRANTS', 'ROLE', 'ROLES', 'SCHEMAS', 'SESSION', 'STATS', 'TABLES'

Though running the hive queries using spark SQL, gave the desired data. Is it even possible to fetch metadata using presto connection? If yes, please help me with it.

Comment: <schema_name>.<table_name> are only place holders for your real database/table, so replace them. And how is the name of the column with the timestamp?

Comment: @nbk Here, <schema_name> and <table_name> are just for demo purpose. In real code, I did replace them.

Comment: your errorcode demonstrates that you haven't replaced it. In prestodb the syntax is `SELECT * FROM mydatabse.mytable ORDER BY mytimecolum DESC LIMIT 1" like you would do it  in mysql

Comment: @nbk actually this is not the actual error. Here, I've replaced the table name displayed in the error with <table_name>

Comment: use the query i posted in my comentg use actual databse, table and column names. btw. SELECT * is a bad choice, as you should use **always** column names  you need

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$file_modified_time` special column

```
SELECT *, "$file_modified_time"
FROM hive.foo.table;
```

Other special columns include:

```
$bucket
$path
$file_size
$partition
```